# UPLOAD Files with Apollo-angular GraphQL Mutation

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I'm attempting to upload a file via a graphql mutation using the Angular Apollo library, but it's not working. Here is my GraphQL mutation:

```js
addAnomaly(params) {
    return this.apollo.mutate({ mutation: this.addAnomalyMutation, variables: { input: params }, context: { useMultipart: true } });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add more of your surrounding code to show how you are passing the file in?

Comment: Have you solved in any way ? I'm having the same problem